# xml to wbxml conversion for activesync in iOS

Tags: xcode, ios6, activesync, wbxml

I have been trying to built an app which will communicate with MS-ActiveSync Exchange. I am stuck at the provisioning part. I need to send a post HTTP request with WBXML content in body. But I could not find anything anywhere to convert xml to wbxml for active sync.

There are some C based libraries available like wbxml2, but can I use them for active sync. There are no code pages provided in the library as mentioned in MS-Activesync Exchange documentation. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use libwbxml. The package has xml2wbxml and wbxml2xml. Code pages are included.

save this as prov.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ActiveSync PUBLIC "-//MICROSOFT//DTD ActiveSync//EN" "http://www.microsoft.com/">
<Provision xmlns="Provision:">
<Policies>
<Policy>
<PolicyType>MS-WAP-Provisioning-XML</PolicyType>
</Policy></Policies></Provision>
```

then:

```
xml2wbxml -a prov.xml -o prov.wbxml
```

You can manipulate wbxml as text.
In https://code.google.com/p/tz-push/

In javascript:

```
 prov.wbxml = string.fromCharCode(0x03,0x01,0x6A,0x00,0x00,0x0E,0x45,0x46,0x47,0x48,0x03,0x4D,0x53,0x2D,0x57,0x41,0x50,0x2D,0x50,0x72,0x6F,0x76,0x69,0x73,0x69,0x6F,0x6E,0x69,0x6E,0x67,0x2D,0x58,0x4D,0x4C,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01)
```

Comment: I am providing the xml string as provided above. Then I am using 'wbxml_conv_xml2wbxml_withlen(xml, xml_len, &wbxml, &wbxml_len, &params);'function to get the wbxml file. But it is not giving the correct wbxml. Where are you using 'xml2wbxml -a prov.xml -o prov.wbxml' function in Xcode project.

Comment: I have an Exchange Server configured and I'm trying just to test the authentication from an iOS app. From a view the user shall enter email, username and password and I want to make the request just to authenticate the user. Can you provide me some guidance how to to that?

Answer (score 0):

wbxml2xml and xml2wbxml are command line programs included with libwbxml. I know nothing about IOS development.

Have a look at https://tz-push.googlecode.com/files/towbxml.js it is xml to wbxml converter written in js. (Can be run in Thunderbird/Workspace or Firefox/Sratchpad.) I know this is not what you want but the code may point you in the correct direction. It uses Sax. So if you have a sax parser available should be easy to port.